# VBA: modify an array as member of an object by reference in a Sub

Tags: vba, pass-by-reference

my Excel-applicatin has a module with utility functions. One of them adds items to arrays:

```
Public Sub addToArray(ByRef arr As Variant, item As Variant)
'Sub adds one element to a referenced array
    On Error Resume Next
    Dim bd As Long
    bd = UBound(arr)
    If Err.Number = 0 Then
        ReDim Preserve arr(bd + 1)
    Else
        ReDim Preserve arr(0)
    End If
    arr(UBound(arr)) = item
End Sub
```

This Sub works perfectly as long as I pass arrays that are not referenced as object members.

```
addToArray arr, item
```

works but...

```
addToArray myObject.arr, item
```

doesn't...

the second call adds the item to an array but loses the reference to `myObject`

I can write a workaround by implementing a method in each class (doesn't need object references because it accesses properties of the same object) but that's not how I wanted to solve this problem.

Pls hälp ;)

Comment: I'm guessing that the ReDim is the cause of why the myObject loses the array. You might want to make a copy of your myObject.arr as tempArray and use that for the call, then reassign that tempArray to your myObject.arr.

Comment: Can't you create a array class that implements the method, like `arr.addToArray item`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, this is not possible due to limitations of VBA.

When you're accessing a public variant field of an object, it's get copied by value, so the original reference is not exposed. And if you declared an array (which is internally a reference type) as a public field, you would get the compile error "Constants, fixed-length strings, arrays, user-defined types and Declare statements not allowed as Public members of object modules"

Comment: But if he adds the objects reference to parameters it should work?